# How to change this code to receive only one msgbox?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have datagridview column with checkboxes. I want to check if there is a selected Row in this column. If its not I want to display msgbox. I can check columns by this but I'm receiving multiple msgboxes for every unchecked row. How to change it to receive only one msgbox?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[5] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

    //We don't want a null exception!
    if (cell.Value == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nie zaznaczono pola!");
    }
}
```

edit:

Thank you for answer. I realized that my problem is more compicated than I thought. My button has to delete selected rows from datagrid. The problem is with foreach because it deletes only first row and still shows msgbox when I use if/else. I need to delete data and if no checkbox selected do msgbox. Here is my button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        object cell = row.Cells["cell_del"].Value;
        if (cell == "yes")
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Rok2016 where ID ='" + row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            wczytywanie_tabeli();
        }

        else 
        {                               
            MessageBox.Show("Nie zaznaczono pola!");
            break;
        }
    }




    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop your loop after you got a null value simply by break the loop if a nullvalue was found:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[5] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

    //We don't want a null exception!
    if (cell.Value == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nie zaznaczono pola!");
        break;
    }
}
```